# Position a triangle along a slider

Tags: wpf, path, slider

I want to extend a slider by a triangle pointing to a fixed position (the triangle will not be moved like the thumb).

The current code draws the triangle at position 0,0.

```
<Path Data="M 0 0 L 6 0 L 3 7 Z" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black"/>
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

In this example the slider represents a % value (the range is not necessarily 0 - 100). The triangle should be positioned at a fixed % value, which is provided via dependency property.
My question is: how do I relocate the triangle to point to that % value (not the thumbs value)?

Comment: that's easy. create a grid with three columns with these widths: 25*, 0, 75*, put the triangle in a canvas in the second column to see it in the 25% position. then you can write a converter to convert the DP value to a `GridLength` to see it in any position

Comment: But how would the conversion look like?

Comment: `return new GridLength((int)value, GridUnitType.Star)` I assumed you know how to write a [value converter](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)

Comment: Sorry, I first did not understand your answer completely. Thanks for your help. But I ended up doing it differently.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, please take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With fixed ratio it would look like:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid Margin="0,-10,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="75*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
            <Path Data="M -3 0 L 3 0 L 0 7 Z" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Slider/>
</Grid>
```

Notice that I changed the path to center it on the canvas.

To make the ratio dynamic you need a converter to be able to bind it to a property (a `double` named `Percent` here)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:GridLengthPercentConverter x:Key="GridLengthPercentConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding 
                Path=Percent, 
                Converter={StaticResource GridLengthPercentConverter},
                ConverterParameter=first"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding 
                Path=Percent, 
                Converter={StaticResource GridLengthPercentConverter},
                ConverterParameter=other"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1">
            <Path Data="M -3 0 L 3 0 L 0 7 Z" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
    <Slider/>
</Grid>
```

Here's how the converter looks like:

```
public class GridLengthPercentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(parameter.ToString() == "first")
            return new GridLength((double)value, GridUnitType.Star)
        return new GridLength(100 - (double)value, GridUnitType.Star)
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```